# How would you translate lagged based column transformation in base r to dplyr pipe?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a paragraph of code I'm having a lot of trouble translating to a dplyr pipe.

Given the following data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tb <- tribble(
    ~time, ~hazard_0, ~hazard_1,
    7, 0.04768284, 0.10710033,
    8, 0.02412410, 0.05590856,
    9, 0.09269841, 0.19662787,
    10, 0.13912236, 0.27908998,
    11, 0.16053845, 0.31418869,
    12, 0.23522180, 0.42422854

)
tb
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>    time hazard_0 hazard_1
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     7   0.0477   0.107 
#> 2     8   0.0241   0.0559
#> 3     9   0.0927   0.197 
#> 4    10   0.139    0.279 
#> 5    11   0.161    0.314 
#> 6    12   0.235    0.424
```

I want to perform the following routine:

```r
tb$surv_0<-c(1:6)
tb$surv_1<-c(1:6)
tb$surv_0[1]<-1-tb$hazard_0[1]
tb$surv_1[1]<-1-tb$hazard_1[1]
for(i in 2:6) {
    tb$surv_0[i] = tb$surv_0[i-1]*(1-tb$hazard_0[i])
    tb$surv_1[i] = tb$surv_1[i-1]*(1-tb$hazard_1[i])
}
tb
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>    time hazard_0 hazard_1 surv_0 surv_1
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     7   0.0477   0.107   0.952  0.893
#> 2     8   0.0241   0.0559  0.929  0.843
#> 3     9   0.0927   0.197   0.843  0.677
#> 4    10   0.139    0.279   0.726  0.488
#> 5    11   0.161    0.314   0.609  0.335
#> 6    12   0.235    0.424   0.466  0.193
```

The routine is the same for `surv_0` and `surv_1`.

<sup>Created on 2019-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

`cumprod` is the function you're looking for.

```
tb %>% mutate(surv_0 = cumprod(1 - hazard_0), surv_1 = cumprod(1 - hazard_1))
```

Note that this is dependent on the data being in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, you absolutely should use `cumprod`, since it will be faster and cleaner. In a more general situation, where object values depend less clearly on previous iterations and you can't get the right output with a combination of the cumulative functions, you can always wrap logic in a function to use it in a pipe. You can either use a very simple one with `accumulate`, or spend the least time translating an existing loop and just put that in a function.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tb <- tribble(
  ~time, ~hazard_0, ~hazard_1,
  7, 0.04768284, 0.10710033,
  8, 0.02412410, 0.05590856,
  9, 0.09269841, 0.19662787,
  10, 0.13912236, 0.27908998,
  11, 0.16053845, 0.31418869,
  12, 0.23522180, 0.42422854
)

surv_fun <- function(current_hazard, next_hazard) {
  current_hazard * next_hazard
}

surv_for <- function(hazard) {
  surv <- numeric(length(hazard))
  surv[1] <- 1 - hazard[1]
  for (i in 2:length(hazard)) {
    surv[i] <- surv[i - 1] * (1 - hazard[i])
  }
  surv
}

tb %>%
  mutate(
    surv_acc = accumulate(1 - hazard_0, surv_fun),
    surv_for = surv_for(hazard_0)
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>    time hazard_0 hazard_1 surv_acc surv_for
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     7   0.0477   0.107     0.952    0.952
#> 2     8   0.0241   0.0559    0.929    0.929
#> 3     9   0.0927   0.197     0.843    0.843
#> 4    10   0.139    0.279     0.726    0.726
#> 5    11   0.161    0.314     0.609    0.609
#> 6    12   0.235    0.424     0.466    0.466
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>